# Does a guide for installation of drupal Cartaro distribution exist?

Tags: theming

I have been trying to install the Cartaro distribution of drupal on windows that makes drupal

a complete geo-stack. I have been unable to find complete documentation for the same and the

installation fails to detect postgis installed on the computer as well as there is some confusion about the terminology for geoserver.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Cartaro's Getting Started](http://drupal.org/node/1719056) guide. Especially see the quoted commands to set up permissions for PostGIS properly.

Additionally, there have been changes to the error reporting of Cartaro in July which should result in more precise error messages in case something is wrong with PostGIS.

Please report any bugs in Cartaro using its [bug tracker](http://drupal.org/project/issues/cartaro) on the Drupal site so that is does not get overlooked. We'd be happy to see a report there regarding the GeoServer terminology along with a more verbose description.